# function which is able to return different types?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function in c++, I am wondering if I can create it such that it is able to return different types of vectors. e.g based on different case it returns vector string, int, double or ...anything.
Is it possible in c++? (I do not want to use overload function with different arg(S) and different returns)
I am very new to C++ and my question may seem to be stupid.

here is a piece of my code:

//zero here means intersection

```
std::vector<??????> findZeros(const mesh::Region& s, char *model) const
{
//Point  
  if( model == "point" )
  {
    std::vector<Vertex> zeros;
    for(Region::pointIterator it = s.beginPoint(); itv != s.endPoint(); ++itv )
    {
      if( abs(Val(*it)) < 1.e-12 )      
      zeros.push_back(*it);
    }
    std::vector<point> zerosP(zeros.begin(), zeros.end());
    return zerosP;
  }
 //line
  else if (EntityS == "line")
  {
    std::vector<line> zerosE;
    std::vector<Point&> PointE;
    for(Region::lineIterator ite = s.beginLine(); ite != s.endLine(); ++ite )
    {
      Line ed = *ite;
        Point P0 = ed.point(0);
        Point P1 = e.point(1);
        if( ......... ) zerosE.push_back(ed);
        else if ( ....... )
        {
         PontE.push_back( P0, P1);
         zerosE.push_back(ed);
        }
      }
```

//here I want to return  "point" or "line with its points" or in upper level our surface.
//I want to do all in one function!
      }

Comment: templates [....]

Comment: Yes, template functions are your friend here. Here is a quick guide: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: What would be the parameters of this function?

Comment: templates can be used to achieved the desired result

Comment: @LuchianGrigore & Mert Well, only if it is to be decided at compile time, of course.

Comment: @MertToka Yes. Templates are your friends. There's nothing more special when friends write you great novels. :)

Comment: `boost::any`, anyone?

Comment: thanks guys, I add a piece of my code as well..

Comment: Never compare C strings with `==`. Use `strncmp`, or, more simply, `std::string`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intended to do by having a vector of references and using the comma operator, which discards the left side (you should turn your warnings on to get one about that), but it won't work well.

Comment: There are a number of bugs in your code: 1. In order to get the string comparison right, I recommend taking the `model` argument of the function as `std::string`. Otherwise `model == "point"` will just be a comparison between pointers to `char`. 2. `std::vector<Point&>` will not work. Use value types or pointers instead of references. 3. You use some names stuff like `EntityS` where I don't know exactly if you mean `model` instead. There are a few things like that. I can recommend going to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're new to programming C++.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Templates

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> func( /* arguments */ )
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    // ... do some stuff to the vector ...
    return v;
}
```

You can call this function with different type in this way:

```
std::vector<int> func<int>( args );
std::vector<double> func<double>( args );
```

### Alternatives

This is one way, if you know the types at compile-time. If you don't know the type at compile-time but at run-time only, then you have different choices:

1. Use `unions`. I can only recommend this, if you have very simple C-struct-like types which are called PODs (plain old data) in the C++ standard.
2. Use some type of variant. For example there is [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) from the Boost libraries or [`QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html) from the Qt library. They are a safe kind of unions on more general types. They also allow some conversions between different types. For example setting something to an integer value will make it possible to read the same value as floating point number.
3. Use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html) which can wrap any type but does not allow conversions between them.
4. Use inheritance and polymorphism. For this case you need a common base class, say `Base`. Then you create an array of pointers to that base preferably with `std::shared_ptrs`. So the array type would be `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`. The `std::shared_ptr` is better than built in pointers in this case because the manage your memory automagically by reference counting.
5. Use a dynamic language that doesn't care about types and performance.

Comment: You had to go and update this to include most of the possibilities I was preparing right before I posted my answer :p Still +1.

Answer (score 14):

**C++17 Update**

If you known the type at compile time, you can use templates as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649242/8769985).

If the type is known at runtime only, with `c++17` as an alternative to `boost::variant` we have the [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using variant_vector = std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>>;

auto get_vector(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        return variant_vector(std::vector<int>(3, 1));
    else
        return variant_vector(std::vector<std::string>(3, "hello"));
}

int main()
{
    auto visit_vec = [](const auto& vec) {
        using vec_type = typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(vec)>::value_type;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<vec_type, int>)
            std::cout << "vector of int:" << std::endl;
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<vec_type, std::string>)
            std::cout << "vector of string:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto& x : vec)
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
    };
    
    std::visit(visit_vec, get_vector(-1));
    std::visit(visit_vec, get_vector(1));

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae030eabc6967195).

In the code above, the function `get_vector` returns a `std::variant` object that either holds a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::vector<std::string>`. The contents of the returned object are inspected using [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Answer (score 6):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but there multiple possibilities for how to do this. Here are a few that come to mind:

**If one of a specific list of return types is decided inside the function:**

Since you edited your question, this seems to be what you want. You might try `boost::variant`:

```
boost::variant<int, double, std::string> foo() {
    if (something) 
        //set type to int
    else if (something else)
        //set type to double
    else
        //set type to std::string
}
```

**If the return type depends on a template argument:**

You can use SFINAE to manipulate overload resolution:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
std::vector<int> foo() {...}

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type>
std::vector<std::string> foo() {...}
```

**If the return type can be anything:**

A `boost::any` would work well:

```
boost::any foo() {...}
```

**If the return type is always derived from a specific class:**

Return a smart pointer to the base class:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> foo() {
    if (something)
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new Derived1};
    if (something else) 
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new Derived2};
}
```

Comment: I try to use boost::variant, but i receive the following error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node

Comment: @user2090491, I can't say I've had need of it, myself, but the Boost docs would be a good place to start. As for the vector, it should work decently well to make it contain variants, which could be any of the defined types, but to set them all to the same type and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use templates, if you know what type to return before you call the function. But you can't have a function, which internally decide to return some type.

What you can do is to create a class which will be a container for returned data, fill object of this class with desired data and then return this object.

```
typedef enum { VSTRING, VINT, V_WHATEVER ... } datatype;

class MyReturnClass {

    datatype d;

    // now either
    vector<string> * vs;
    vector<int> * vi;

    // or
    void * vector;      

 }

 MyReturnClass * thisIsTheFunction () {

       MyReturnClass * return_me = new MyReturnClass();

       return_me->datatype = VSTRING;
       return_me->vs = new Vector<String>;

       return return_me;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To update @chris' answer, since C++17 you can use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
#include <variant>

std::variant<int, double, std::string> foo() {
    if (something) 
        //set type to int
    else if (something else)
        //set type to double
    else
        //set type to std::string
}

auto result = foo();
if (std::holds_alternative<int>(result)) {
    int value = std::get<int>(result);
}
```