# Exactly same function but data struture returned would be different

Tags: c++, templates, code-reuse

I have a function `foo()`. I want it to either return a `std::queue` or a thread safe queue object. What's the best way of doing this? I considered templates but not sure they fit the situation. I could copy and paste the entire body of `foo()` where one would be `std::queue foo1()` and the other would be `MyQueue foo2()` and just change the type of the data structure. But that would be ugly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function which is able to return different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649136/function-which-is-able-to-return-different-types)

Comment: A function template sounds fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I think function templates fits good for this situation

e.g.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

// Create a different type of queue
template <typename T>
struct another_queue : std::queue<T> {};

// Your function foo
template<typename T>
T foo()
{
    T q;
    for (auto v : {1, 2, 3, 4}) 
        q.push(v);
    return q;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = foo< std::queue<int> >();
    while (not a.empty())
    {
        std::cout << a.front() << "\n";
        a.pop();
    }

    auto b = foo< another_queue<int> >();
    while (not b.empty())
    {
        std::cout << b.front() << "\n";
        b.pop();
    }
}
```